# Users with only 1 reputation but many posts. How can it happen?

Tags: support, reputation

Why can the reputation of a user  still be 1 in spite of their many posts with high scores? Their reputation even did not changed after I voting up for their answer.

Comment: Since they are suspended. When the suspension ends they recover their reps.

Comment: I generalize the post a bit. I think it's a reasonable question to ask. While many among us might be aware of this, I can see it being confusing. I see no harm in recording it. (Maybe it's a duplicate though.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Users can be placed in [timed suspension](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/account-suspension/info) by per-site moderators or SE staff (the reasons for this are varied and as a rule the specific reason is not discussed publicly).

During this period the reputation is displayed as 1; there is also a note on the users profile page that indicates their current status.

Once the suspension ends the reputation is restored (there is no direct points penalty associated with suspension) and the user can keep using the site as before (if they chose to do so).

Another reason why a user can have an unusually low number of points relative to the number of posts are massive distribution of [bounties](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/bounty/info) (we had some users that donated away basically all their points).

Comment: OP says the reputation didn't change even after upvoting an answer, so I think that for the case(s) that interested OP, we can rule out boutnies.

Comment: What if the answer was CW?  Or, they first maxed-out for the day and then set a bounty?  Many things are possible. ;-)  But, yes, typically it's a suspension especially if it is really 1 point, with or without that extra information. The "another reason" was more an aside.